# How do you sign an assembly that was generated by an ILMerge operation?

Tags: .net, signing, strongname, ilmerge

I managed to use ILMerge to merge all the assemblies I have in my project into a single assembly, but the problem is there doesn't seem to be a way to sign the merged assembly.

Is there some sort of command line option or command that I can run that would let me add a strong name to the merged assembly generated by ILMerge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the following commandline to sign:

```
al /out:MyAssembly.dll MyModule.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk
```

If you would like to learn more, please visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx

Answer (score 8):

ilmerge ... /keyfile:key.snk